# For duplicate rows create fractional value to populate another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am generating a dataset from nothing. 
Let's say my data looks like this:

```
Country |Quantity |ProdBatchNo | Volume | Batch_Quantity 
--------|---------|------------|--------|----------------
Mars    |     0   | B9-3       | 1.00   | 6439.849161    
Jupiter |     0   | B9-3       | 0.50   | 6439.849161    
Neptune |     0   | B9-3       | 1.25   | 6439.849161
```

I want to *randomly* assign a quantity of product to each country and then calculate the overall % of the Batch_Quantity that that country is assigned to. 
The only way I could think of doing this is to divide 6439/3 = (2146), then Quantity would become 1.00 x 2146 = 2146 for Mars, 0.50 x 2146 = 1073 for Jupiter and 1.25 * 2146 = 2682 for Neptune.

However, when I total these up to get the overall % of the batch these figures don't add up. It becomes 33% for Mars, 16% for Jupiter and 41% for Neptune. This gives 90% in total but I want the Batch_Quantity to be completely allocated to these countries with no remainder.

I realise this is a maths problem as much as a data one and it's hard to explain what I'm at as I am *generating this dataset myself* so the quantity of ProdBatchNo assigned to a country can be *completely random* as long as all the Batch_Quantity is allocated between the countries.

My way of doing this before there were duplicate rows for ProdBatchNo was straightforward - I rounded Batch_Quantity down to the nearest 100 and then divided it by volume (size of container) to generate Quantity. However, I want to split the total Batch_Quantity into 3 Product batches based on volume and assign them to my hypothetical countries Mars, Jupiter and Neptune, as well as generate the %_Vol_allocated to each ProdBatchNo (of the total Batch_Quantity).

Sorry I am not very good at explaining what I am looking for. 
Is anyone following me? 
Thanks :)

Comment: hey how you get quantity 2750 for mars?, " rounded Batch_Quantity down to the nearest 100 and then divided it by volume " 6400 * 1 = .. ?

Comment: yeah they were just placeholder figures. I removed them

Comment: ok so now, you need to show us, what you expect as a result dataframe, replace "?' with your expected result,

Comment: take a look on my answer after edits

Comment: ok take a look on my answer, is that  ok for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple *proportional* division. You want to affect a part of `Batch_Quantity` to each country respecting:

- the sum of the individual quantities must be equal to `Batch_Quantity`
- the individual quantities must be proportional to `Volume`

Just do it:

```
df['%_Vol_allocated'] = (df.Volume / df.Volume.sum()) * 100
df['Quantity'] = df.Batch_Quantity * df['%_Vol_allocated'] / 100
```

This assumes a single Batch in the dataframe. If you could have more than one, you could groupby on `ProdBatchNo`:

```
for _, sub in df.groupby('ProdBatchNo'):
    df.loc[sub.index, '%_Vol_allocated'] = sub.Volume / sub.Volume.sum() * 100
    df.loc[sub.index, 'Quantity'] = sub.Batch_Quantity * sub['%_Vol_allocated'] / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Country":['Mars','Jupiter','Neptune'],"Quantity":['0','0','0'],"ProdBatchNo":["B9-3","B9-3","B9-3"],
                 "Volume":["1.00","0.50","1.25"],"Batch_Quantity":["6439.849161","6439.849161","6439.849161"]})





countries=df['Country'].count()

df['Quantity']=(df['Volume'].astype(float)*df['Batch_Quantity'].astype(float)/countries)
sum_Quantity=df['Quantity'].sum()
Batch_Quantity=df['Batch_Quantity'][0]
rest=float(Batch_Quantity)-float(sum_Quantity)
rest_to_add=rest/3
df['New_Quantity']=df['Quantity']+rest_to_add
df['%_Vol_allocated']=((df['New_Quantity'].astype(float)/df['Batch_Quantity'].astype(float))*100).round(2)
print(df)

  Batch_Quantity  Country ProdBatchNo     Quantity Volume  New_Quantity  %_Vol_allocated
0    6439.849161     Mars        B9-3  2146.616387   1.00   2325.501086            36.11
1    6439.849161  Jupiter        B9-3  1073.308194   0.50   1252.192892            19.44
2    6439.849161  Neptune        B9-3  2683.270484   1.25   2862.155183            44.44
```

now`%_Vol_allocated` of `New_Quantity` is around 100%
in column `['New_Quantity']` you can see updated values

Comment: Thanks, I think I can somehow adapt this answer to apply it on duplicate rows with different ProdBatchNo's

Comment: @skiventist ok, take a look now, i've divided the difference for sum() of Quantity, compared to Batch_Quantity, and added to New_Quantity